# How can I make JavaScript search in both upper-case and lower-case?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script to search a CSV and return results for a small website. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make "LOREM IPSUM", "lorem ipsum", and "LoReM IPSsum" all return the same results.

The "City Type" functions as expected and is the only column that allows me to search by mixed case and return results. I expect this based on the "toLowerCase()" in that section of the script. However, when I try to make the other search items look the same, the entire search function breaks.

Can you help me with being able to search mixed case?

Script:

```
d3.csv("SubCityData.csv").then (function (data) {
    var movies = data;
    var button = d3.select("#button");
    var form = d3.select("#form");
    button.on("click", runEnter);
    form.on("submit", runEnter);

function runEnter(e) {

    d3.select("tbody").html("") 
    
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation()
    
    var inputValue = d3.select("#user-input").property("value");

    var filteredMovies = 
    movies.filter(movies => {
        return (
            movies['Coords'].includes(inputValue) || 
            movies['City Type'].toLowerCase() === (inputValue).toLowerCase() || 
            movies['Culture'].includes(inputValue) ||  
            movies['Alliance'].includes(inputValue) ||  
            movies['Owner'].includes(inputValue)
        )
    });
    
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/0.10.0/lodash.min.js">

    for (var i = 0; i < filteredMovies.length; i++) {
        let output = filteredMovies
        d3.select("tbody").insert("tr").html(
            "<td>" + (output[i]['Coords'])+"</a>"+"</td>" + 
            "<td>" + (output[i]['City Type'])+"</td>" +
            "<td>" + (output[i]['Culture'])+"</td>" +
            "<td>" + (output[i]['Alliance'])+"</td>" +
            "<td>" + (output[i]['Owner'])+"</td>" ) }
        }
    });
```

Currently, "City Type" functions how I need. So I changed all to the following, but when I do the same for "Owner" it breaks the search function:

```
    var filteredMovies = 
    movies.filter(movies => {
        return (
            movies['Coords'].includes(inputValue) || 
            movies['City Type'].toLowerCase() === (inputValue).toLowerCase() || 
            movies['Culture'].toLowerCase() === (inputValue).toLowerCase() ||  
            movies['Alliance'].toLowerCase() === (inputValue).toLowerCase() ||  
            movies['Owner'].includes(inputValue)
        )
    });
```

When I use this line, it also breaks the search function:

```
var inputValue = d3.select("#user-input").property("value").toLowerCase();
```

If someone could help with the "Owner" line, I think I would be good to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for all cases if type sensitivity isn't important so you can make all the strings lowercase:

```
var inputValue = d3.select("#user-input").property("value").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: When I change my var line as suggested, the search function stops working. Is there a way to add the .toLowerCase() to the "Owner" line under return, since that's the only one I haven't made work (see edit)?